# Prove that a graph is 2-connected if and only if each pair of vertices are contained in a common cycle.

Tags: graph-theory

Is this proof vigorous enough?

Also, is the question complete? In the textbook that I'm using, a $k$-connected graph $G$ means at least $k$ vertices must be removed to disconnect $G$. But after removing $2$ vertices from a triangle graph, isn't a graph with one vertex connected?

(UPDATED) Proof:

Let $G$ be a connected graph with at least $4$ vertices. Let $u$ and $v$ be any of its two vertices, $u' (\ne v)$ be a vertex adjacent to $u$, and $v'(\ne u)$ be adjacent to $v$. Note that either $u'$, $v'$ or both must exist. (Assume neither exists. If $u$ and $v$ are adjacent, $G$ either has $2$ vertices only or is disconnected. If $u$ and $v$ are not adjacent, a path (length $> 1$) connecting $u$ and $v$ has a vertex $w$ adjacent to either $u$, $v$ or both).

(1) Let $G$ be $2$-connected, so at least $2$ vertices must be removed to disconnected $G$. Now, assume $u$ and $v$ are not in a common cycle:

1. If $u$ and $v$ are adjacent, then removing $u$ or $v$ will disconnect $u'$ and $v$ or $u$ and $v'$. (Suppose a path without $u$ connects $u'$ and $v$. This is a contradiction, since $u' \to \cdots \to v \to u \to u'$ creates a cycle with $u$ and $v$. The same applies to $u$ and $v'$).
2. If  $u$ and $v$ are not adjacent, then there is $\ge 1$ path(s) connecting $u$ and $v$. Note that any two paths must have a common vertex, so there is only one pairwise internally disjoint path (having two such paths will create a common cycle containing $u$ and $v$). By applying [Menger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem#Vertex_connectivity) on vertex connectivity, which states that the size of the minimum vertex cut for $u$ and $v$ is equal to the maximum number of pairwise internally disjoint paths from $u$ and $v$, $G$ has a cut-vertex.

In both cases, we only need to remove $1$ vertex to disconnect $G$, contradicting $G$ is $2$-connected. Hence, $u$ and $v$ are in a common cycle.

(2) Let $u$ and $v$ be contained in a common cycle. Now, assume $G$ is not 2-connected i.e. $G$ is $1$-connected ($0$-connected means $G$ could be disconnected. ($> 2$)-connected means $G$ is still technically $2$-connected):

1. If $u$ and $v$ are adjacent, then we must remove $u'$ and $v'$ to disconnect $uv$ from other vertices. If $u'$ and $v'$ are adjacent (i.e. there are only $4$ vertices), then we must remove $u$ and $v'$ or $v$ and $u'$ to disconnect $v$ and $u'$ or $u$ and $v'$ (the same applies vice versa).
2. If $u$ and $v$ are not adjacent, we must remove at least two vertices to disconnect $u$ and $v$ (a cycle containing $u$ and $v$ means there are at least two pairwise internally disjoint paths, so we must remove at least one vertex from each path).

In both cases, we must remove at least $2$ vertices to disconnect $G$, so $G$ is 2-connected.

Hence, a graph is $2$-connected if and only if each pair of vertices are contained in a common cycle.

Comment: "By removing one vertex in the path, u and v are disconnected." is a little problematic.  How do we know we can remove such a vertex?  How do we choose said vertex?

Comment: There's possibly an issue with the first argument too: how do you define when two paths are "distinct"?  For me, this isn't sufficient for the conclusion, and you'd need a stronger condition on the paths to reach the conclusion.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, for your first comment, we can only remove a vertex if u and v are non-adjacent. Suppose this is the case, I need to consider the case when u and v are adjacent, correct?
Proof: If u and v are adjacent, then removing u/v disconnects u'v/uv' where u' and v' are adjacent to u and v respectively. Given that G has more than 2 vertices and is connected, u' and/or v' must exist. There can also be no cycle between u'v/uv' since u and v are not contained in a cycle.
Is adding this proof enough to conclude 2-connected => any u and v in a common cycle?

Comment: @BrianMoehring, for your second comment, will "To disconnect the pair of vertices, at least one vertex from each of the two paths connecting the vertices in the cycle must be removed" work? But after the first comment, that appears to work if u and v are non-adjacent. For adjacent u and v, removing u' and v' will disconnect uv from the rest of vertices in the cycle

Comment: @BrianMoehring, for your first comment, we can choose any vertex in the path connecting uv that is not u and v.

Comment: Also, I just realised that a cycle graph of 3 vertices also satisfies "each pair of vertices in a common cycle". But, is it 2-connected? If I remove 2 vertices from it, there will be just one vertex. By default, a graph with just one vertex is connected, right?

Comment: Even if $u$ and $v$ do not lie on a common cycle, there may be multiple $u-v$ paths. This makes it harder to find a vertex whose deletion disconnects $u$ from $v$: maybe you delete a vertex on one $u-v$ path, but a different $u-v$ path which did not use that vertex survives. (The assumption that $u$ and $v$ do not lie on a common cycle guarantees that there cannot be two $u-v$ paths that don't share any other vertices; it does not obviously follow that there's a vertex $w$ which lies on every single $u-v$ path.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov, (1st part) I'm sorry but if there are multiple $u-v$ paths, isn't it guaranteed that u and v lie on a common cycle since $p_1$ can get you from $u$ to $v$ and $p_2$ can get you back to $u$ from $v$? Or, does 'a common cycle' have a different meaning? (2nd part) The only case that I can think of when $w$ does not exist is when $u$ and $v$ are adjacent. I will fix my mistake later. Is there any other cases where $w$ does not exist?
P.S. I'm self-studying graph theory so my understanding could be off.

Comment: A cycle cannot repeat vertices. So if paths $p_1$ and $p_2$ share a vertex, then following $p_1$ from $u$ to $v$ and $p_2$ back to $u$ would not create a cycle. Also, the vertex $w$ *does* always exist (if $u$ and $v$ are not adjacent), since the claim we're trying to prove here is true, but my point is that we can't just assume this - it requires careful proof.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, Thank you for feedback, now I understand why $p_1$ and $p_2$ might not create a cycle. Also, when writing a proof, do I need to prove everything I claim or at least refer to other proofs? Because, vertex $w$ exists if $u,v$ not adjacent is kind of self-evident.

Comment: (1) If the existence of $w$ seems (incorrectly) self-evident, perhaps you can think about the role of the proof as explaining how you would *find* $w$ in an arbitrary graph satisfying the conditions. (2) Using Menger's theorem is fine, but a bit silly, since the entire claim you want is just the connectivity-2 case of Menger's theorem.

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682913/show-that-if-g-is-2-connected-then-for-any-two-vertices-u-and-v-there-e/4436913#4436913

Comment: @Mike, Thank you. Yes, it does, but only for the first half of the question. Is there any guidance on proving "if any pair of $u$ and $v$ is in a common cycle, $G$ is 2-connected" (and if this is true at all)?

Comment: @MishaLavrov, (1) Can you explain why it is incorrectly self-evident? My understanding is if $u$ and $v$ are not adjacent and if the graph is connected, then the path connecting $u$ and $v$ must have some other vertices, so they must be a vertex $w$. Or, maybe this is proof that I should write? (2) Does "a bit silly" mean "overkill"? (3) Thank you for answering my questions! It's very helpful.

Comment: (1) There is of course another vertex on the path connecting $u$ and $v$. But not every such vertex is suitable to be a vertex $w$ whose removal $u$ from $v$; we want a vertex $w$ that lies on *every* $u-v$ path. (2) If you are going to use Menger's theorem, you could write a much shorter proof. There is educational value in trying to write this proof without using Menger's theorem, though.

Comment: @MishaLavrov (1) I thought you were referring to any vertex. In that case, yes, vertex $w$ is incorrectly self-evident. (2) Yes, I agree. I just read the proof by Mike. (3) Also, I have asked another question in the post. I would appreciate it if you could answer it as well.